# Can I uninstall ubuntu and install lubuntu without causing my dual boot system to go awry?

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, lubuntu

I love unity, but my system isn't up to par. My system often hangs up while coding, and it's very annoying. I was thinking of switching to a lighter DE. So, I installed budgie. But, the problem still continues.

So, to revert to my original question: How can I uninstall ubuntu and install lubuntu, without harming my windows 7 partition?

If anyone has a better suggestion to me, please feel free to let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lubuntu just uses LXDE. You can install that alongside whatever other desktop environments you have installed.

Run

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

to install it. Log out, look for a gear icon or Budgie logo icon, press it and select LXDE or Lubuntu Desktop before logging back in.

Fresh installs are usually better, but this is easier and takes less effort.

If you want to install fresh, the Ubuntu installer should have an option to `Erase Ubuntu and install Lubuntu` (or whatever it says). **Make sure you're not selecting `Erase disk`!**

If it doesn't have that option, choosing `Something Else...` will allow you to erase just the Ubuntu partition and then select it as the install location.

Comment: Beat me by seconds!

Comment: @CollDue96 Victory! :p

Comment: dang, dude! That was pretty quick! :D Thanks for all the help! @Zacharee1